# Wrong posts number on Review section

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Lately it's happening to me this:

After completing one or more "First Posts" reviews, I go back to the Review Section main page: https://stackoverflow.com/review

And the post counter shows that there are still posts to review. I click the link to review them, but there is nothing.

Refreshing the page doesn't solve the issue: it shows the wrong number again.

Comment: Caching. The numbers are cached for a couple of minutes, so this is most likely [meta-tag:status-bycaching].

Comment: Obligatory: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Review is probably our heaviest database hitter, so we've had to add caching to those counts; usually it's 5 minutes on them.

Comment: I really didn't think the reviews counter was so heavy to manage, compared with the rest of the site.