# Review overview shows two suggested edits for a long time, but the review queue is empty

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, meta

When I went to the review overview on Meta on 08.01.2015, 19:16, it listed two open items in the suggested-edits queue, however when I clicked on the queue, I was told that the queue had been cleared. When I went back to the review overview, however, the edits were there again.

Since the icons for recent reviews had not moved, I suppose that these were still the same two items waiting for review, and since phenomenon lasted for **half an hour** now, I would rule out [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237845/255554) or [locked edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238898/255554) to be the reason for this.

After a while, the phenomenon ceased, with one new reviewer popping up in the icon list of recent reviewers.

I had not performed or skipped any suggested-edit review from the queue at that point.

[image: obligatory screenshot with free-hand markings]

A similar phenomenon occurred for several hours up to 11.04.2015, 11:05: The review overview showed two suggested edits and when I went to the suggested-edits queue, it was cleared. Sometimes, edits that I could review appeared, but two phantom edits remained.

Comment: Suggested edits are being locked when someone is reviewing them and can be accessed only with direct link. (for five minutes or so, I think)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I am aware of this and mention it in the question now as another possibility that I ruled out (it’s three minutes by the way).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong posts number on Review section](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237845/wrong-posts-number-on-review-section)

Comment: @bluet: That does not explain the timescales, I observed.

Comment: Did you recently suggest an edit, like for a tag wiki, that you can't review yourself (because it's your edit)? ....the same thing happened to me today, with the review number on top of the page, after I suggested a tag wiki edit.

Comment: @Shokhet: No, I didn’t.

Comment: Actually, I just edited another tag wiki -- the number shows up in the top bar, but not on the review queue page, so my theory is wrong anyway.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I can see it now - been happening for an hour(?) now... (but I +1'd ages ago!)

Answer (score 4):

If I'm not mistaken, these might be edits you don't have access to.

The [*Approve Tag Wiki Edits*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege is available at 5k rep, but access to the [edit review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) is available at 2k.

So, these edits might be two tag wiki edits.

Comment: That may indeed be, but then it’s really strange that I never encountered this phenomenon on other sites where I am between 2k and 5k reputation (or their Beta equivalents).

Comment: Also, this would still be an undesirable behaviour.

Comment: both of those reviews turn up on the suggested edits queue, so there has to be something

Comment: That's most likely the case, there were quite a few tag wiki suggested edits here on MSE today. /cc @Wrzlprmft

Comment: @ShadowWizard: That matches with me observing the issue right now again with 4 suggested edits.